# Arima formula in R

Tags: r, arima

I am using "Arima" to build a MA(1) model for "Airpassengers", the code is bellow:

```
 test3=Arima(AirPassengers,c(0,0,1))
```

The result is

```
Series: AirPassengers 
ARIMA(0,0,1)            with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ma1      mean
      0.9642  280.6464
s.e.  0.0214   10.5788

sigma^2 estimated as 4265:  log likelihood=-806.43
AIC=1618.86   AICc=1619.03   BIC=1627.77
```

I wonder for the final formula, which one is correct :

(1) Yt=280.6464+et+0.9642et-1

(2) Yt=280.6464+et-0.9642et-1

Comment: ARIMA models are additive models by construction, so in your case of a MA(1) model: `x_t = mean + w_t + ma1 * w_{t-1}`. See e.g. [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/48).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above, we can explicitly reconstruct the source data using the model coefficients and residuals in our MA(1) model equation `x_t = mean + w_t + ma1 * w_{t-1}`. In doing so we can confirm the correct sign of the additive terms.

1. Fit an MA(1) model to data `AirPassengers`:

   ```
   fit <- arima(AirPassengers, c(0,0,1));
   ```
2. Reconstruct the data using the estimated model coefficients and residuals that are stored in `fit$residuals`.

   ```
   # Reconstruct the data from the model coefficients and residuals
   # x_t = mean + w_t + ma1 * w_{t-1}
   x.model <- coef(fit)["intercept"] + fit$residuals + coef(fit)["ma1"] * stats::lag(fit$residuals, k = -1)
   ```
3. We plot the original data `AirPassengers` and the reconstructed data. Because both time series data would overlap, we vertically shift the reconstructed data by `shift = 50`. You can confirm that they indeed overlap if you set `shift = 0`.

   ```
   shift <- 50;
   ts.plot(AirPassengers, x.model + shift, gpars=list(xlab = "Date", col = c(1, 2)))
   ```

[image]

So we conclude that the MA(1) model equation is indeed `x_t = mean + w_t + ma1 * w_{t-1}`, and not `x_t = mean + w_t - ma1 * w_{t-1}`.